# Efficiency of construction of stl container based on a function return

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference, move-semantics, return-value-optimization

I have a factory function which return a stl container:

```
const std::vector<int> f(...) {
    std::vector<int> retval;
    return retval;
}
```

I guess it is ok to define a stl instance as follow(no error):

```
const std::vector<int> stl_instance(f(...));
```

But is it efficient to do so?

Is the temporary stl object directly assigned to `stl_instance`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning a const rvalue is an anti-pattern in C++11. First consider returning non-const rvalues:

```
std::vector<int> f(int n) 
{ 
    return std::vector<int>(n); 
}

int main() 
{ 
    std::vector<int> v; 
    v = f(3); 
}
```

In C++98/03, this code will go to the heap at least twice:

1. To create the vector inside of f (if the RVO applies)
2. To assign from f's return to v.

If your compiler does not apply the RVO, you get 3 heap allocations.

In C++11, you only get 1 heap allocation: to create the vector inside of `f`. This happens regardless of the RVO. The reason is that all the STL containers have move constructors and move assignment operators that have the signatures

```
vector( vector&& other );
vector& operator=( vector&& other );
```

The rvalue references `&&` will move the resources from inside your creation function directly to their destination. However, your code has the signature

```
const std::vector<int> f(int n) 
{ 
    return std::vector<int>(n); 
}
```

will disable the move semantics because a T&& (i.e. the argument of the move constructor and assignment operator)  will not bind to a const rvalue parameter (i.e. the return value of your function). This effectively makes your code run as under C++98/03 (i.e. with 2 or 3 heap allocations).

Answer (score 1):

It is fine and legal code.
The compiler will take care of necessary optimizations(*if it can*) through copy elision.

The temporary `f(...)` is guaranteed to live at least until the expression ends. Note that the expressions ends just after the return from `stl_instance(f(...))`, to be precise `;`(*the semicolon at the end of call*). So it is perfectly valid.

**C++03 Standard §12.2/3:**

> Temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the full-expression (1.9) that (lexically) contains the point where they were created.

Comment: @AlokSave It is legal but certainly not fine C++11 code because const return values disable move semantics.

Comment: @KarthikT Move semantics are disabled with const return values.